# ggplot2 version 0.9.3.1 won't load into R 3.0.2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I accidentally deleted my old version of ggplot2, so I downloaded the new version, and when I use

```
library(ggplot2)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘colorspace’
 Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?  I tried reinstalling the older version of ggplot2 in both R 3.0.2 and R 3.0.1 (where it previously worked!) and it says the package is not available.

If anyone has a solution  to how to fix the loading of the new version or how to get the old version work again, I would be indebted - I really need to plot something with ggplot!!

Cheers

Comment: Rather than downloading ggplot2, which won't come with the required packages, you could install it using `install.packages("ggplot2")` from your R terminal. Does that fix the problem?

Comment: Hi David, thanks - sadly I get the same error again...

Comment: what if you try `install.packages("colorspace")`?

Comment: Haha - thank you!  That worked!!  Sorry for my idiot question.  I can delete it if that would be appropriate?!

Comment: Not an idiot question. It's possible someone could have the same problem and run into this from Google, so I suppose I'll post it as an answer

Comment: it helped me mate... lol

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Install the missing colorspace package by executing the following line in R:

```
install.packages("colorspace")
```

Comment: But why is colorspaces missing and doesn't it get downloaded when GGplot is installed or updated? Similar with package scales: not downloaded on update, just an error when you try require

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by installing **Tk** and **Tktable** in my linux machine.